# using vector within a class

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I'm relatively new to c++. Today I was experimenting with classes and the vector container provided by the standard library.

If I compile and run this snippet of code anything works fine:

```
class foo{
// the class content here
};

int main() {
vector <int> v;
v.push_back(4); // simply adds an integer to the vector, it works fine.
return(0);
}
```

However, if I put the vector definition inside the class and try to simply add an integer to the vector from within the class, I get these errors:
Unknown type name 'p'
Expected member name or ';' after declaration specifiers

The code that is giving me these errors is:

```
class foo{
protected:
vector <int> v;
v.push_back(4);
};

int main() {
return(0);
}
```

Can you help me please? I'm using Xcode for mac os X as my IDE; I've searched for solutions to my problem, but I found nothing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `v.push_back(4);` when would you expect that line of code to execute?

Comment: Your declaration of the vector is fine.  All executable code associated with the class (ie. your `v.push_back(4)`) must be in _methods_ (also known as _member functions_).  If you declare a method for your class, you can do `v.push_back(4)` from there.  You probably should read up a little more about how classes, members and member functions work.

Comment: @JoeZ to be fair, `int main()` is not a method/member function. It is just a plain function. And "relatively" compared to what? These are the basics.

Comment: you need to read up on the C++ syntax, you cannot place a v.push_back there.

Comment: @cicto:  But you can't manipulate a `protected` or `private` member in a class from a non-member or non-friend.  (If you're going to be picky, you could point out I haven't really talked about friend classes and friend functions.)

Comment: In short, you can't put code just anywhere in a class body, only inside of functions.

Comment: You should not use protected data members, btw.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to populate your vector member in a member function, such as a constructor:

```
class foo{
protected:
    vector <int> v;

public:
    foo()
    {
        v.push_back(4);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The statement `v.push_back(4)` won't compile within the body of the class because statements like that aren't allowed. Only declarations. Therefore it's considered a syntax error. You can initialize the vector from the constructor:

```
foo::foo()
    : v{ 4 }
{
    // or
    v.push_back(4);
}
```

or inside the class using *aggregate-initialization* (C++11):

```
class foo
{
    std::vector<int> v{4};
    //                ^^^
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The function call

```
v.push_back(4);
```

isn't in a function. If it isn't in a function, when do you expect it to execute?

**The fix:**

```
class Foo {
protected:
     vector<int> v;
public:
     Foo();  // Constructor declaration
};

Foo::Foo() { // Note: This should be in a source file
    v.push_back(4);
}
```

This means that 4 is added to the vector when the class is instantiated. Since the class has a blank constructor, it will happen immediately.